# Binning Dates in R

Tags: datetime, r

I struggle with dates and times in R, but I am hoping this is a fairly basic task.

Here is my dataset:

```
> str(temp.df)
'data.frame':   74602 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ time : POSIXct, format: "2011-04-09 03:53:20" "2011-04-09 03:53:15" "2011-04-09 03:53:07" "2011-04-09 03:52:39" ...
 $ value: num  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...

> head(temp.df$time, n=10)
 [1] "2011-04-09 03:53:20 EDT" "2011-04-09 03:53:15 EDT" "2011-04-09 03:53:07 EDT" "2011-04-09 03:52:39 EDT"
 [5] "2011-04-09 03:52:29 EDT" "2011-04-09 03:51:56 EDT" "2011-04-09 03:51:54 EDT" "2011-04-09 03:51:46 EDT"
 [9] "2011-04-09 03:51:44 EDT" "2011-04-09 03:51:26 EDT"
```

and for convenience...

```
> dput(head(temp.df$time, n=10))
structure(c(1302335600, 1302335595, 1302335587, 1302335559, 1302335549, 
1302335516, 1302335514, 1302335506, 1302335504, 1302335486), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "")
```

What I am looking to do:

- How can I find how many hours are between the min and max date/time?
- What's the best way to create summaries of my data using 1-hour time buckets?

Any help you can provide will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Look at the (excellent) vignette for package zoo -- it is in there.

Comment: Personally, I've found that avoiding time in general is sometimes easier than trying to get it into an R friendly format. I split the date into columns and work with raw numbers instead that refer to day, month, year, hour, minute, second.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the proper time series packages [zoo](http://cran.r-project.org/package=zoo) and/or [xts](http://cran.r-project.org/package=xts). This example is straight from the help pages of `aggregate.zoo()` which aggregates POSIXct seconds data **every 10 minutes**

```
 tt <- seq(10, 2000, 10)
 x <- zoo(tt, structure(tt, class = c("POSIXt", "POSIXct")))
 aggregate(x, time(x) - as.numeric(time(x)) %% 600, mean)
```

The `to.period()` function in [xts](http://cran.r-project.org/package=xts) is also a sure winner.  There are countless examples here on SO and on the r-sig-finance list.

Comment: Could you please clarify what your mod 600 is doing? The buckets are every hour, this I see with variable x. All that the aggregate line seems to do to x for me data is add 47 seconds to the start and end of each bucket. What's the point of this?

Comment: See the comment: `# aggregate POSIXct seconds data every 10 minutes`

Comment: cut(time(x), breaks="10 mins") is a great way to simplify that second parameter to the aggregate function.  There is an example of doing it this way under the documentation for the aggregate function in the zoo package. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/zoo/zoo.pdf